# Are there any flow types definition for react-native styles?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I'm making a react native component and using Flow to define the property types like this:

```
type Props = {
    text: string,
    textStyle: object
}
```

Those properties are then passed to the Text component inside my component. Are there any Flow type definitions for react-native that will allow me to do something like this:

```
textStyle: TextStyle
```

Now Flow would be able to check that the textStyle value contains only keys that are allowed for Text component style.

I see that there are interface definitions for TypeScript (React.TextStyle) but can't find anything for Flow.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 3:**

Current best practice is:

```
import type {
   ViewStyleProp,
   TextStyleProp,
   ImageStyleProp,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet';
```

**Update 2:** The following [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/9c29ee1504a66979d7e87f60e42d437e044a1ada) makes things simpler, as of today flowtype styles are as follow.

```
type StyleValue = {[key: string]: Object} | number | false | null;
type StyleProp = StyleValue | Array<StyleValue>;
```

**Obsolete:** The [following PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/da047966e4c2064a48e02ff74830c99808d8194b) fixes it, can be found from v0.52.0

It is possible to do the following:

```
// @flow

import type { StyleObj } from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetTypes';

type Props = {
    style?: StyleObj
};
```

Following discussion on: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/631#issuecomment-282009393

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{[key: string]: Object | number | string | null}` instead?

Comment: @AMB's answer below is more up-to-date (as of 2018-09-13).

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

`StyleObj` is no longer part of StyleSheetTypes.

Now import:

`{LayoutStyle, TransformStyle, ShadowStyle, ViewStyle, TextStyle, ImageStyle, DangerouslyImpreciseStyle} from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetTypes';`

In your case, you should:

`import { TextStyle } from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetTypes';`

Comment: After following your advice I'm seeing ```ViewStyle Application of polymorphic type needs <list of 0-2 arguments>. (Can use `*` for inferrable ones)```.

**EDIT** Resolved it by importing `ViewStyleProp` as opposed to `ViewStyle`!

Comment: `import type { ViewStyleProp } from "react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet";`