# Validate Style property type in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-proptypes

I have an component that takes a property which contains the syling for a sub-component. I would like to ensure `propTypes` correctly validates it's type. I can from the React Native code that it has a [`ViewStylePropTypes`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/View/ViewStylePropTypes.js) module that provides this, however I cannot seem to find where/if it is exposed.

What I want to know is, what is the correct way of validating this without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any flow types definition for react-native styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41779714/are-there-any-flow-types-definition-for-react-native-styles)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To enforce styling restrictions for `PropTypes` just use the following, dependent on what type of component you are rendering:

```
MyComponent.propTypes = {
  /**
  * Style to be applied to the containing <View>
  */
  buttonStyle: View.propTypes.style,
  /**
  * Style to be applied to the inner <Text>
  */
  textStyle: Text.propTypes.style
}
```

For example `Text.propTypes.style` will show a YellowBox warning when `border` is defined in the`textStyle` property.

**Note:** This will also result in the regular `Failed prop type supplied to Text...` warning that occurs when rendering `Text` inside a component with an invalid style attribute.  The `propTypes` validation allows your custom component to also validate this at the same time, giving you better granularity.

Comment: Thank you for that, I feel really silly that I didn't think about that.

Comment: No problem, this one is relatively well hidden!

Comment: @G0dsquad is this still valid solution? I am getting `Warning: View.propTypes has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version of ReactNative. Use ViewPropTypes instead.` error in dev console.

Comment: Have you tried switching over to ViewPropTypes.* @Wojtek ?