# Extending flow `type Props` to include prop types from another component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-typed

I have following component that mainly relies on `Image` from react-native

```
// @flow
import React from "react";
import { Image } from "react-native";
import { deviceWidth } from "../services/device";

type Props = {
  width: number,
  ratio: number
};

class RatioImage extends React.Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { width, ratio, style, ...props } = this.props;
    return (
      <Image
        {...props}
        style={[
          {
            width: deviceWidth * (width / 100),
            height: deviceWidth * (width / 100) * ratio
          },
          style
        ]}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default RatioImage;
```

I was able to type annotate my own props, but in example above `style` throws an error

> [flow] property `style` (Property not found in Props) const style: any

I know that in typescript I can just extend interface to Image one, is there something in flow that I can use in order to make my props inherit all types from `Image` somehow? How would I even import such types from react-native?

**EDIT**
I found out about concept called intersection types and tried this

```
import { Image, type Image as ImageProps } from "react-native";
type Props = ImageProps & {
  width: number,
  ratio: number
};
```

but style is still throwing an error, although different one

> [flow] property `style` (Property cannot be accessed on any member of
>   intersection type intersection Member 1: ImageProps Error: property
>   `style` Property not found in React component Member 2: object type
>   Error: property `style` Property not found in object type) const
>   style: any

Comment: You might want to check this out & see if `Image.propTypes.style` could work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758937/851045

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, React Native is not 100% consistent in the way it uses flowtypes.

If you were trying to do the same for the `Text` component, you could simply import the type definition from the internal `TextProps` module provided by the global Haste namespace, and create your own supertype using Flow type unions:

```
import type { TextProps } from 'TextProps';

type ExtendedTextProps = TextProps & {
  additionalProp: string
};
```

That said, there is no `ImageProps` module for you to import. If you look at the [`Image` (iOS) component types](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/Image.ios.js#L41-L156), they're still expressed as PropTypes.

At this time, I believe, the easiest way for you to add full type coverage for your custom image component would be look at the Image component's PropTypes and convert them to Flow types by hand. Some of the more complex field types such as [ImageSource](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageSource.js) and [ImageStyle](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetTypes.js#L204-L209) already exist as flowtypes.

I'm not sure what the core team's intention is going forward, but it might be worth considering contributing the type defs to React Native itself and solving this problem for future users.

Comment: `TextProps` is a good direction to start with, I'll go over inconsistent modules and will try to see how easy it is for me to port them to this convention

Comment: With `import type { TextProps } from 'TextProps';`, I get the error message: `Cannot resolve module 'TextProps'`. How did you get it to work?

Comment: You could write it like this: `type ExtendedTextProps = Text.propTypes.style & {` and avoid additional `import`s: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758937/851045